# delete img tag and remove double space into single space using preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have this string

```
<img src="xxxxxx"/>     Title<br>Desc
```

How to replace double space into one space and also  tag. please help. thanks.

I'm using following code (not working) :

```
preg_replace('<img src="(.*?)"\/>', "", $str, -1);
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: my string is: "   <img src="xxx">   Title"

Comment: And where did you copy that regex from? Has no relevance. Also enable error_reporting. -- Why do you need to replace spaces there anyway? The browser does compact them anyway. And what tag is expected in the output. Explain better, or concretise with an output example.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you can use [strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) instead

```
$str = '<img src="xxxxxx"/>     Title';
echo strip_tags($str); // Title
```

Also using `preg_replace`

```
$str = '<img src="xxxxxx"/>     Title';
echo preg_replace('#<img.*?(\/>|$)#s', '', $str, 1); // Title
```

[**DEMO.**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/m50gjt)

Comment: how to remove double space only?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$str = '<img src="xxxxxx"/>     Title';
$repl = (preg_replace('/( {2,})+/', " ", strip_tags($str));
var_dump($repl);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
string(6) " Title"
```

Comment: how to remove only <img> tag ?

Comment: For that just `strip_tags($str);` would work as other answer states.

Comment: i'm using complex str inside str. so it wont work :(. how to remove double space with preg_replace? thanks before

Comment: I have provided you both answers i.e. stripping image and removing double space. If you post your complex string in your question I can investigate.

Comment: Great to know it worked for you. If this answer helped you solve your problem, please consider marking it as "accepted", so users facing a similar problem in the future will be able to see it easily.